# adMob Ad Banner without ovarlaping my main view in android application

Tags: android, listview, admob, tabview, adbannerview

I am a beginner in android and I need your help.

I have added an adMob adBanner at a bottom of my screen programmatically. Now what I want is, 
when the ad appears, it will push the view/views up and make enough spaces for it (example: it will push the list view up if my layout contains a listview or a tabView up if it contains a tabView).

How can I do that ??

Comment: It's easier to do in xml, just define a relative layout and put the banner at the bottom and everything else above it.

Comment: I know, but It will take a fixed area in my layout for all the time. When the add wont show, the area will remain bank   which  I don't want

Comment: That's true but it will take that space anyway when the ad is displayed.

Comment: that's allowed, but a n empty fixed area is not allowed for my app :(

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://android-elements.blogspot.ro/2011/06/view-visibility.html). your banner is a view, I suggest to use visibility.